# Node Sequelize - insert date "as is" without converting to UTC

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Im trying to run a simple query like

```
Insert into table (somedate) values ('2018-06-11 23:59:00')
```

but Sequelize executes it as

```
Insert into table (somedate) values ('2018-06-12 02:59:00')
```

Is there an option to set the date "as is" without converting or changing it in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually tell sequelize not to convert it to UTC while reading and you can also provide a time zone for while writing

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('db_name', 'postgres', 'postgres', {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  dialectOptions: {
    useUTC: false //for reading from database
  },
  dialect: 'postgres',
  timezone: '+05:30', // for writng
});
```

Comment: This would not work if timezone has multiple offsets for daylight savings time.

Comment: this works in inserts but when you make select a table, datetime columns return with timezone changes!

Answer (score 2):

I've found a hacky solution for you. You have to edit a Sequelize file which is not always an option, but it may solve your problem.

Open `sequelize/lib/data-types.js` and you will see

```
DATE.prototype._stringify = function _stringify(date, options) {
  date = this._applyTimezone(date, options);

  return date.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS Z');
};
```

The `Z` in the `date.format()` function means "current time zone", try removing the `Z` :

```
return date.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS');
```

Comment: instead of editing the Sequelize file change it after required, like below:
`let Sequelize = require('sequelize')
Sequelize.DATE.prototype._stringify = function _stringify(date, options) {
  return this._applyTimezone(date, options).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS');
}; `