# Why sequelize between dates with difference in hh/mm/ss return empty

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

when I run sequelize query below with date format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

```
var query = "select * from alert_detail_full as a\
    where a.client_id = '" + clientId + "'\
    AND a.timestamp between '" + startDate + "' AND '" + endDate + "';";
    db.sequelize.query(query).spread(function (sresult, met) {
        console.log(sresult)
        var alerts = [];
        if (sresult != false) {
            sresult.forEach(function (e) {
                alerts.push(e);
            });
        }
        response = {
            alerts: alerts
        };
        next(response);
    });
```

my sequelize runs this query:

```
SELECT * FROM alert_detail_full as a    
WHERE a.client_id = 'CL001' 
AND a.timestamp BETWEEN '2018-06-08 00:02:00' AND '2018-06-08 00:06:00';
```

If I put this query directly inside mysql, it will give me a list of results.
But in sequelize `sresult` returns `[]` , however if I create difference in days not minutes it will return list of results like below.

```
{
            "client_id": "CL001",
            "collector_id": "C01",
            "sensor_id": "S001",
            "value": "4341435.452947",
            "timestamp": "2018-06-08T08:01:00.000Z",
            "alert_yellow": "60230000.000000",
            "alert_red": "456000.000000",
            "alert_flag": "low"
        },
```

***Update***

If i put a big gap between hours such as `T00:02:00 - T20:02;00` it will generate results in sequelize as well, but if small gap in minutes I can only get results in MYSQL and sequelize always return `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize converts date into `UTC` by default while inserting and reading. You can tell sequelize not to do that like this

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('db_name', 'postgres', 'postgres', {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  dialectOptions: {
    useUTC: false //for reading from database
  },
  dialect: 'postgres',
  timezone: '+05:30', // for writng
});
```

Also look at the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798083/node-sequelize-insert-date-as-is-without-converting-to-utc/50807931#50807931)