# I am unable to set local "timezone" in MySQL using sequalize node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime, sequelize.js

I am using *node* and *sequalize* to create web API. Everything is working correctly, but when I update `user` table as follow:

```js
var localDate=getDateTime();
console.log(localDate)
//output: 2021/06/03 18:01:22 this datetime is in local formate(GMT+0500),exactly which I need in `MySQL`
var data = { ActivationDate:localDate};
User.update(data, {where: { Email: req.body.email }}).then(num=>{/*whatever*/})
```

The database is updated, but in `MySQL` the `ActivationDate` column of the `user` table is updated according to `UTC` which is `2021-06-03 13:01:22`, and I need it according to local formate(GMT+0500) `2021/06/03 18:01:22`.

To prevent this behaviour, [I also search from here, but these solutions are not working for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798083/node-sequelize-insert-date-as-is-without-converting-to-utc)

I also add following in config.js file:

```json
 dialectOptions: {
    useUTC: false, //for reading from database
    dateStrings: true,
    typeCast: function (field, next) { // for reading from database
      if (field.type === 'DATETIME') {
        return field.string()
      }
      return next()
    },
  },

  timezone: '+05:00'
```

But still, the `ActivationDate` is stored according to UTC.
How I can save my local DateTime in `ActivationDate` column.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL, correct?

Try `timezone: 'Asia/Karachi'` in your options.

`TIMESTAMP` items in MySQL are always stored in UTC, even if you provide them in a local time zone. They're always converted to the timezone you choose.

`DATETIME` items are always stored in local time.

Comment: as per your answer "TIMESTAMP items in MySQL are always stored in UTC, even if you provide them in a local time zone" ,it means there is no way to store in DateTime according to the local time zone in MySql?

Comment: on the other hand, I added timezone: 'Asia/Karachi' in my options, but still, DateTime is stored according to UTC time zone.